# Perl Search and Capture Line After

Tags: perl, search

Alright, so this is probably a pretty easy question to answer, but I'm struggling with it.  I'm trying to get my program to capture everything after a certain word and then print it.  For example, if the input text is

bar foo foo foo foo

Then I want the output to be "foo foo foo foo" if I am searching for bar.  I hope my question makes sense.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I'm very new to perl, so the more explanation you can give, the better.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

*ARGV = *DATA;  # for demo only

while (<>) {
  print "line $.: $1\n" if /bar\s+(.+)/;
}

__DATA__
you can't see me
bar foo foo foo foo
nope
```

Output:

```
line 2: foo foo foo foo
```

Comment: For the OP,  the text in the //  after the 'if' statement is a Perl regular expression.  $1 is used to reference the 1st group.  Groups are denoted by ().  Read up on Perl regular expressions as they are very useful.

Comment: Great! Is there any (easy) way to add what line it is from? like if your example, the output would be: line 2: foor foo foo foo

Comment: @user1440061, `print "$.: $1\n";`

Comment: @user1440061 The special variable `$.` contains the current line number. See the [perlvar documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) and the updated answer for an example.